# submit form on check box checked and unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py

```
class SearchKeyword(Form):
    status = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'id':'status'}),required=False, label="Status")
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#status:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
    $("#status-form").submit();
    return false;
});
```

I want to show Live report by default,so the check box is checked.If it is checked it will show the Live report alone,if unchecked it shows Live as well as  Test reports.I need to submit the same form for checkbox checked as well as for check box uncheck.I tried with the above code,the problem is it is showing Live reports but page gets refresh again and again.

Comment: You have to put it in an event and not in a function, executed when the page is loaded

Comment: `return false` does nothing special in there. All that code does is check all checkboxes and submit the form. Not sure I understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: How to handle this using event.

Comment: @elclanrs on page load the check box should checked,if checked i want to show Live reports alone, and if i uncheck the checkbox  it show both Live as well as test reports.Both reports i can display by submitting the same form.How to do this.

Comment: @elclanrs can i get any update for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var chkBox = $('#status:checkbox');
    chkBox.on('change', function() {$("#status-form").submit();});
    chkBox.attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Tamil,I tried this by default check box is checked,but not showing the Live reports(form not posted),if i uncheck the check box the page gets refresh the automatically the check box gets checked